# Dimension of difference of eigenspace and span of a eigenvector.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$. Let $r$ be the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$. Show that the dimension of the space of the left eigenvectors of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda$ is also $r$.

**My approach:**

The sum of the geometric multiplicity of all eigenvalues is n. Assume there are $m$ distinct eigenvalues.
$$\sum_{i=1}^{m}GM(A, \lambda_i) = n$$

where $GM(A, \lambda)$ is geomtric multiplicity of a matrix wrt. eigenvalue $\lambda$.
It is given that for some $k,$ where $1 \leq k \leq n$
$$GM(A, \lambda_k) + \sum_{i=1 , i \neq k}^{m}GM(A, \lambda_i) = n$$
$$\sum_{i=1 , i \neq k}^{m}GM(A, \lambda_i) = n-r$$

Comment: It's really unclear about your question,,,are all $\lambda_i $ distinct? If they are,,then G.M of each eigenvalue must be 1,as you are taken sum of G.M of exactly $n$ eigenvalues.

Comment: My bad, I forget to mention. Since it was not mentioned in the question, I have assumed that there are $m$ distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: Your conclusion is ok....